# Is there any Jenkins plugin that allow manual approval for build before promoted code to production?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, production-environment, continuous-delivery, dev-to-production

I have a query regarding Jenkins's plugin for approving a job. I want manual approval to build a job when code promoted to production. I tried to find a plugin but not able to find any solution. I know spinnaker provides continue delivery but I don't want to use a [Spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/).

Answer (score 6):

There is a plugin called : **Input**

- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/ (documentation)
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-input-step (download)

This step pauses Pipeline execution and allows the user to interact and control the flow of the build. Only a basic "process" or "abort" option is provided in the stage view.

In order to test, just create a pipeline item and put this code:

```
node {
  stage('Build') {
    echo "building"
  }
  stage('Deploy to testing') {
    echo "deployed"
  }
  stage('QA Team certification') {
    input "Deploy to prod?"
  }
  stage('Deploy to prod') {
    echo "deployed"
  }
}
```

Proposed steps of this pipeline flow could be:

- build application
- deploy to testing environment
- in this step, execution is paused

[image: pipeline]

- Quality Assurance team, start the **human** certification. They must ensure that everything works : previous functionalities and new functionalities
- QA engineer, go to jenkins, search a specific build and click on blue box under **QA Team certification** stage. Just proceed or abort options are available:

[image: approval]

- If **proceed** option is clicked, the next step in your pipeline will start. If **abort** option is clicked, the pipeline ends.