# How can I get a bitbucket pipeline to stop and ask me to input variables?

Tags: bitbucket, devops, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket should pause and ask me to input a value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

Closest option is to define the value for some variables **before** the pipeline is triggered, **but only for `custom` pipelines** https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-start-conditions/#Custom--manual--pipeline-variables

I know no CI system that allows you to interact with the scripted commands. Maybe you should explain what are you trying to accomplish because most usually a non-interactive approach is simpler and more secure (e.g. SSH login without password prompt)

Comment: It's possible in Jenkins, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776779/is-there-any-jenkins-plugin-that-allow-manual-approval-for-build-before-promoted